# Combine two arrays into a new structure in python

Tags: python, arrays

Lets say, I have two arrays:

Array1

```
from = ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04']
```

And then array2:

```
to = ['2022-02-01', '2022-02-02', '2022-02-03', '2022-02-04']
```

Now by using the both, i need to create a combined structure array without changing the orders:

Lets say, the expected output is as follows:

```
output = [{'from': '2022-01-01', 'to': '2022-02-01'}, 
{'from': '2022-01-02', 'to': '2022-02-02'}, 
{'from': '2022-01-03', 'to': '2022-02-03'}, 
{'from': '2022-01-04', 'to': '2022-02-04'}]
```

The [0] of from should match [0] of to data. Likewise, how to convert the array ? Am yet to start and dont know where to start so i dont have any code to show. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` and list comprehension for that -

```
from_ = ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04']
output = [{'from': f, 'to': t} for f, t in zip(from_, to)]
```

Comment: This is list comprehension not dictionary comprehension

Comment: You are right, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` function to take on one value from each list at a time. For example:

```
from_arr = ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04']
to_arr = ['2022-02-01', '2022-02-02', '2022-02-03', '2022-02-04']
result = []
for from_elem, to_elem in zip(from_arr, to_arr):
  result.append({"from":from_elem,"to":to_elem})

print(result)
```